# Combinatorics: 3 dimensions --> 8 types

Tags: combinatorics

I am assisting a Grade 11/12 student to learn combinatorics. I have observed that combinatorics questions fall into 3 "dimensions" as below

1. Pattern making vs Set making. That is, Order matters vs Order does not matter
2. Repeats allowed vs Repeats not allowed. That is, an element can be repeated vs elements cannot be repeated
3. All distinguishable elements vs some identical elements

So, a given Combinatorics question belongs to one of the two options from each of the above "dimensions", making 8 different types. An example of a "**question type**" is, "Order matters + Repeats not allowed + Distinguishable elements"

- Q1) Are there any other "dimensions" that I am missing?
- Q2) Are there web resources that analyse and summarise these 8 types in one place
  providing examples and how to solve each type?

Comment: See the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way).